# Datetime object to string containing AM/PM

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I currently have a `datetime` object with time that looks like `06:00:00` and `am` trying to convert it to a string that looks like "`6:00 am`".

I have been trying to use the Python `Strftime` libraries but am having trouble, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `%I:%M %p`, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()

>>> now
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, 14, 6, 49, 62354)

>>> print(now.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
02:06 PM
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for a list of the different format codes.

If, as your question implies, you need it *without* a leading zero on the hour, and in lower-case, you can just use regular expressions for the former and `lower()` for the latter:

```
>>> import re

>>> print(re.sub("^0", "", now.strftime("%I:%M %p")).lower())
2:06 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime( '%H:%M %p' )
'15:09 PM'
```

Comment: You probably want to use `%I` rather than `%H`: `15:00 PM` is a bit redundant :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo that's intentional =) but notice, we both failed to give OP what he wants -- the hour without the leading `0`, like `6:00`, not `06:00`